# Angular2 this is null in component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular-promise

I'm expecting some weird situations where "this" is null inside a component.
SO far, I saw it in two situations:

**1)** When the promise is rejected:

```
if (this.valForm.valid) {
            this.userService.login(value).then(result => {
                if(result.success){
                    this.toasterService.pop("success", "Exito", "Inicio de session correcto");
                    this.sessionService.setUser(result.data);
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
                }
                else{
                    this.error = result.code;
                }
            },function(error){
                console.log("ERROR: " + error);
                this.error = "ERROR__SERVER_NOT_WORKING";
                console.log(this.error);
            });
        }
```

In the function(error) this is null so I cannot assign the corresponding error.

The service is working in the following way:

```
  login(login : Login) : Promise<Response> {
      return this.http
      .post(this.serverService.getURL()  + '/user/login', JSON.stringify(login), {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
      console.log('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
      return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
```

So the this value is lost when the service handleError is called.

**2)** - Using sweetalert

```
logout(){
        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
            }).then(function() {
                this.sessionService.clearSession();
                this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
        }, function(){
            //Cancel
        });
    }
```

Here when I confirm and I try to execute the clearSession is called,  this is null.

I don't know if they are two different issues or if both are cause by the same issue.

Comment: Use arrow functions. They bind `this` to the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `() => {}` (ES6 arrow function) as a callback in order for `this` to refer to the component, as the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) does not create its own `this` context:

```
this.userService.login(value).then(
    (result) => {
        this.toasterService.pop("success", "Exito", "Login successful!");
    }, 
    (error) => {
        // now 'this' refers to the component class
        this.error = "SERVER_ERROR";
    }
);
```

Still, if you want to use `function(){}`, you can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) component's `this` context to the callback function as following:

```
this.userService.login(value).then(
    function(result) {
        this.toasterService.pop("success", "Exito", "Login successful!");
    }.bind(this), 

    function(error) {
        // now 'this' refers to the component class
        this.error = "SERVER_ERROR";
    }.bind(this)
);
```

The same should be applied for your second use case.

Comment: Thanks!! New in angular2 so I didn't knwe that!